Function to return HTML to be used as vis.js template from inside nuxt/vue 3 application
I'm creating a gantt chart using vis.js. I need custom templates to create more appealing items on my timeline. The documentation states examples for handlebars.js and react.js but not vue. And I'm struggling to get it working.
Current (working state):
export interface TimelineItemExtended extends TimelineItem {
  contentFirstLine?: string,
  contentSecondLine?: string,
  contentThirdLine?: string
}

const template = (item: TimelineItemExtended) => {
  let html = ""
  if (item.contentFirstLine) {
    html += `<div class="font-weight-bold">${item.contentFirstLine}</div>`;
  }
  if (item.contentSecondLine) {
    html += `<div>${item.contentSecondLine}</div>`;
  }

  if (item.contentThirdLine) {
    html += `<div>${item.contentThirdLine}</div>`;
  }
  if (html !== "") return html;
  return `
    <div>
        ${item.content}
    </div>
  `
}

const options: TimelineOptions = {
  template: template
}


In the future I need something like this to be used as the template:
<script setup lang="ts">
import {defineProps} from 'vue';
import type {TimelineItemExtended} from "~/components/Timeline.vue";

const props = defineProps<{ item: TimelineItemExtended }>();

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <!-- Render the first line if it exists -->
        <div v-if="item.contentFirstLine" class="font-weight-bold">{{ item.contentFirstLine }}</div>

        <!-- Render the second line if it exists -->
        <div v-if="item.contentSecondLine">{{ item.contentSecondLine }}</div>

        <!-- Render the third line if it exists -->
        <div v-if="item.contentThirdLine">{{ item.contentThirdLine }}</div>

        <!-- Fallback to render the entire content if the first line does not exist -->
        <div v-else>
          {{ item.content }}
        </div>
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        <v-btn prepend-icon="mdi-table-eye" @click="navigateTo(`/table/?product=${item.content}`)" flat/>
      </v-col>

    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.font-weight-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

Found another post: how to render custom vis.js item templates using vue 3
But I couldn't get it working for my application (async function only renders empty items).
I tried using vue's render function h(..) but it only returns vnodes and this results in empty items on the gantt chart.
The template function should return either a string or the HTMLElement:
export type TimelineOptionsTemplateFunction = (item?: any, element?: any, data?: any) => string | HTMLElement;

